# What Type should myCustomDictionary.Values return?

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, language-concepts

If you have the object `Dictionary<k, v> myDictionary`, then `myDictionary.Values` will be of type `Dictionary<k, v>.ValueCollection` and `myDictionary.Keys` will be of type `Dictionary<k, v>.KeyCollection`.

I don't understand why the type of `myDictionary.Values` is not something like `IEnumerable<v>`, `IList<v>` or something else.

Now, with that in mind, if I create a custom kind of dictionary; `Dictionary2<k1, k2, v>`, should `myCustomDictionary.Values` return an `IEnumerable<v>`, or a custom implement of ValueCollection? More importantly, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` does in fact implement `ICollection<TValue>` and therefore also `IEnumerable<TValue>`.

The reason why the property is *typed* the way it is is likely for performance reasons: since the methods of this class are not virtual, they can be exactly resolved during JIT compilation, instead of requiring vtable lookups for each method call at runtime.  This effectively removes one level of indirection from each method you call on the collection.  (It also gives the JIT the option to inline those method calls!)

Of course, you can implicitly convert the object to `ICollection<TValue>` if necessary, so there is no loss of functionality here, just a bit of (micro) optimization.

In your case, there is no reason you cannot return `ICollection<TValue>`, but you can return a more specific type if you would like.  If you do, then you will have to explicitly implement the interface property `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values` to satisfy the interface:

```
private ValueCollection valueCollection;

public ValueCollection Values
{
    get { return valueCollection; }
}

ICollection<TValue> IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values
{
    get { return valueCollection; }
}
```

This correctly implies that any performance benefit will only be given to consumers of the class if they are using a reference typed as your collection type; there will be no performance advantage if they take a reference to `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, as they will have to choice but to access your value collection through `ICollection<TValue>` anyway.

In my work, I have not found the performance difference to be significant enough to warrant returning anything more specific than `ICollection<TValue>`.  Remember: always benchmark, and never prematurely optimize.

Comment: What, this answer has a lot of information in it. Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: `List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` are the most frequently used implementations of `IList<T>` and `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. As such, preventing unnecessary interface dispatch calls has an aggregate effect across the entire .NET ecosystem, and contributes to a mobile device power advantage that Java will never be able to touch (due to their overuse of overridable methods in infrastructure classes).

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary<k, v>.ValueCollection` implements `IEnumerable<v>` and `Dictionary<k, v>.KeyCollection` implements `IEnumerable<k>`.  It's not like the results that are returned aren't enumerable.

By returning an actual class that implements `IEnumerable` rather than typing the result as `IEnumerable` they have the ability to include a bit of additional functionality as well.  For example, both collections have a `Count` property, which isn't easily accessible from any `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Note that `ICollection<T>` has a Count property, and `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values` returns an `ICollection<T>`.  So *any* implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` *must* return a `Values` object that supports the `Count` property anyway.  The more-specific type of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values` does not in any way provide extra functionality that I can see.